# sidebar parameters (before_widget, before_title) not Working

Tags: sidebar

I have just recently tried to use the sidebar parameters (before_widget, before_title) but html tags i used inside are not working

```
function noorband_widget_setup(){
    register_sidebar(array('name' => 'Sidebar',
                'id' => 'sidebar-1',
                'class' => 'custom',
                'description' => 'Standard Sidebar',
                'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s"',
                'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                'before-title' => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h1>',
         )
);
```

the title should be heading one
but that seems like a normal text
[image]

Comment: Have you inspected the HTML to see what tag is actually being output? Just looking at it visually won't tell you because that depends on the CSS.

Comment: I have not applied any style yet. and i m  using the bootstrap framework

Answer (score 5):

The issue is in your params array. There was a missing closing `>` in `before_widget` and `before-title` should be `before_title`.

Try this:

```
array(
    'name' => 'Sidebar',
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'class' => 'custom',
    'description' => 'Standard Sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h1>',
  )
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Welcher. The problem has been solved by your help

Comment: @GullAQA can you mark the answer as correct please :)